# FluentValidation on ApplicationService Endpoint

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to add `FluentValidation` to my ABP `ApplicationService` as described in [this article](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Validating-Data-Transfer-Objects#fluent-validation).

I added the NuGet package, and also specified the dependency on my main application module:

```
[DependsOn(
    typeof(MyCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpQuartzModule),
    typeof(AbpFluentValidationModule))]
public class MyApplicationModule : AbpModule
{
    // ...
}
```

I then created a validator:

```
public class MyDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<MyDto>
{
    public MyDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).Custom(MyCustomRule);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Then in my app service I simply have the following endpoint:

```
public class MyAppService : ApplicationService
{
    // Constructor

    public void MyEndpoint(MyDto input)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

The `MyDtoValidator` constructor is never called. I presume one has to call the validator manually for application services.

Comment: As far as I have tried and know, you need to call the validator manually.  **new Validator().Validate(object);**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aspnetboilerplate resolves the validators using IOC [check source code](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/search?q=IValidator)

In the source code for the related unit tests [FluentValidationTestController](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/059db7626b3642114b7a2ba7d15b6a14304640dd/test/Abp.AspNetCore.Tests/App/Controllers/FluentValidationTestController.cs) they defined the validator class inside the controller.

I'm assuming that you created 2 seperate classes for the validator and controller, thus the validator factory isn't finding the `MyDtoValidator` class.

TLDR: try adding the interface `ITransientDependency` to the `MyDtoValidator` class